# C# Performance optimization: Avoid drawing points at the same location, increase size instead

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, unity-game-engine

I am visualizing a point cloud in Unity. My C# script reads the RGB data of a .png file and draws a particle at the corresponding position( x=r, y=g, z=b).

Pictures of course have multiple pixels of the same color, currently they are still drawn but i want to avoid that and increase the size of the corresponding particle instead.

I already tried checking with Array.IndexOf() for existing particles and increasing their size when found.

The problem with this solution is that it is very slow. The possible amount of different particles is 256*256*256 and when I tried it with only 50*50 particles it took over a minute to compute. An example with 4*4 worked well but this is far from what I need.

I already did think about making a list with existing particles. Maybe the list search is faster, but then I also would have to transform the list to an array. 
Another idea is to just store a counter value in an int[256,256,256] and then iterating through it to create particles. But this would also be a huge overhead.

Any ideas for a better approach are very welcome.

Edit: Creating all the particles including the unneccesary ones is very fast, just taking 1-2 seconds to compute a million particles. For this visual an rendering improvement I hope that I dont need to increase the computation time by factor 10 and above.

Comment: Depending on how sparse the data is, you might use a Dictionary instead of the 3D array. You could, for example, have keys equal to 65536*x+256*y+z

Comment: I also was thinking about that. One problem would be that i need to have an array of particles in the end. But i will implement this solution and check how fast it is.

Comment: Works pretty well with dictionary, time consumption is very low, thanks.

Comment: Great! Nice to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure on the size of your dataset, but having tested this quick bit of code with 1million items, it seems pretty quick (<0.5s to generate data and generate weighting).

Assuming your RBG list looks like the following:

```
var rbgList = new List<RBG>();
```

then a quick bit of LINQ to provide grouping by unique RGB combinations with number of unique occurences would be like:

```
var grouping= 
    rbgList.GroupBy(val => 
        new {val.R, val.B, val.G}, (key, group)=> 
        new {RBG= new RBG(key.R, key.B, key.G), Count = group.Count()})
    .Select(g=>g)
    .OrderBy(g=>g.Count);
```

Then you can itterate through 'grouping', getting the RBG value and the Count, allowing you to locate the x/y/z coords you need then scale the point size based on the count.

Hope that helps